# Get web page complete data

Tags: curl, wget

I'm using busybox tools and I want to take all http links in a web page. I save an example link page by using curl or wget. However, it saves the page as html. **How to do it with curl or wget commands?**

```
example webpage = http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/
```

The following data was saved in text format with firefox browser.

```
Index of /wp-includes/test/

Name <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/?ND>                                                                             Last modified <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/?MA>         Size <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/?SA>  Description  <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/?DA>

------------------------------------------------------------------------
up Parent Directory <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/>                                                                 28-May-2019 02:15        -       
[CMP] v1.0.zip <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/v1.0.zip>                                                                         28-May-2019 02:15       4k       
[CMP] v1.1.zip <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/v1.1.zip>                                                                         28-May-2019 02:15       4k       
[CMP] v1.2.zip <http://www.turanevdekorasyon.com/wp-includes/test/v1.2.zip>                                                                         28-May-2019 02:15       4k       

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Proudly Served by LiteSpeed Web Server at www.turanevdekorasyon.com Port 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the  **F**ile | save **A**s feature of Chromium and save the web page in [MHT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) after toggling the experimental "Save Page as MHTML" option on, by visiting the link "chrome://flags/#save-page-as-mhtml" in the Chrome browser.

Comment: I should be use curl or wget command in shell script file.

Comment: If you want to use those specific tools, then you should ask for that in your question. Suggest you click [edit] and spell that out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in using **curl** or **wget**? Use **lynx**:

```
lynx -dump 'www.example.com'
```

it will output all the links, shown and hidden.

Comment: I'm using busybox tools. Not every command is available. No lynx command. I need to recompile the operating system for lynx. I can't do that.

Comment: Something like  wget -qO- http://www.example.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'    ?

Comment: Yes but this command doesn't give result.